# Novice looking to make this stylish mouse hover effect

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

Hopelessly novice, but dedicated. 
Using Wordpress.

*I'd like to be able to do this:* 
http://www.ericryananderson.com/

**On hover, the images turn greyscale and captions appear**. 
All is smooth.

My initial hopes of finding a easy plugin that switches images upon hover has been crushed.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Arvid

Comment: Please provide codes what you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Next time try to make your question title more informative (for example - "Greyscale overlay on hover on images", which looks better than "Make this stylish mouse hover effect"). Also, you should also try to do some research on your own so we know what is your level of knowledge and that you have at least tried to solve your problem by your own. That's how your next question will be answered faster and not downvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can simply add plain CSS and HTML code to your site, then this is the structure:

HTML:

```
<div class="cool-card">
    <img src="whatever.png">
    <h2>Whatever text you want to show</h2>
</div>
```

And then, in CSS:

```
.cool-card {
    /* Add here any custom style (width, height, etc.) to the card */
}

.cool-card > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.cool-card:hover > img {
    filter: saturate(0); /* Makes the image black and white, by setting saturation to 0 */
}

.cool-card > h2 {
    /* If you want to change the look of the text, do it here */
    display: none;
}

.cool-card:hover > h2 {
    display: block;
}
```

If you can't, I'm sorry, but I've tried :)

Comment: This answer has the right idea but I'd suggest using `grayscale(100%)` instead purely because it makes it more obvious when reading the code, and either `opacity` or `visibility` for the h2 so you can apply a transition to it.

Comment: Oh yeah, opacity is better. And yes, grayscale is also better. 

Comment: Glad you agree! Upvoted regardless because the concept of your answer I believe solves the question, just wanted to suggest some aesthetic improvements.

Comment: Greatly appreciated! Can I apply this HTML and CSS code to only ONE of the images on one specific page? How would I go about that?

Comment: @ArvidOttosson - ask one question at a time.  This person was kind enough to answer your question, even though it doesn't comply with StackOverflow guidelines.  Please upvote / accept the answer, and if you need more help, ask another question (but please review the Help, particularly How To Ask, before asking another question)